# Get List of Localized Items

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I need to get the list of localized items of a publication programatically using coreservice in tridion. Could any one suggest me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I know is to use search functionality:

```
var searchQuery = new SearchQueryData();
searchQuery.BlueprintStatus = SearchBlueprintStatus.Localized;
searchQuery.FromRepository = new LinkToRepositoryData{IdRef = "tcm:0-5-1"};
var resultXml = ClientAdmin.GetSearchResultsXml(searchQuery);
var result = ClientAdmin.GetSearchResults(searchQuery);
```

Comment: Apparently I completely misunderstood the question. I'm surprised that anyone wants a list of all localized items within one publication. But indeed, if this is the case searching for the items like you proposed is a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.How can i link the above code in getting the components of the publication

Comment: @user1523958 Just add `searchQuery.ItemTypes = new[] {ItemType.Component};` or `BasedOnSchema` search parameter

Answer (score 9):

I would use the GetListXml method and specify a BluePrintChainFilterData filter object.

```cs
var subjectId = "[TCM Uri of your item]";
var filter = new BluePrintChainFilterData
                 {
                     Direction = BluePrintChainDirection.Down
                 };

var subjectBluePrintChainList = coreServiceClient.GetListXml(subjectId, filter);
```

You then still need to verify the localized items from the received list.

This wasn't in my original answer, and probably isn't complete because I don't take into account namespaces, but the following would work to select the localized (not shared) items.

```cs
var localizedItems = subjectBluePrintChainList.Elements("Item")
    .Where(element => "false".Equals(element.Attribute("IsShared").Value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: This code will find all the local copies of the given item, but the question is `list of localized items of a publication`, so all items from a single publication that are localized

Comment: I don't blame Arjan for misunderstanding the question. And I definitely gave him an up vote for using this cool API. :-)